# Select one from multiple cloud clients using configuration

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection

I have created a sample solution that will have multiple message broker implementations like Azure Service Bus and Rabbit MQ, for now they just log different messages to distinguish which is used. I would like to configure ("MessageBroker--Name" as below) which message broker client my solution should use from the available implementations. I found that this is a good use case for strategy pattern and implemented the same. The goal is to make the solution have multiple implementations of any service but let configuration decide which one to use.

AppSettings:

```
"MessageBroker": {
 "Name": "RabbitMq",
 "ConnectionString": "dummy-connection",
 "QueueName": "sample-queue"
}
```

Program.cs:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
builder.Logging.AddJsonConsole();

builder.Services.AddSingleton<IMessageBrokerContext, MessageBrokerContext>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IMessageBrokerClient, NotConfiguredClient>();

var app = builder.Build();
var logger = app.Logger;

try
{
    var messageBrokerContextService = app.Services.GetRequiredService<IMessageBrokerContext>();

    using var loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(
        loggingBuilder => loggingBuilder
            .SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Information)
            .AddJsonConsole());
    
    var messageBrokerConfiguration = builder.Configuration
        .GetSection("MessageBroker")
        .Get<MessageBrokerConfiguration>();

    IMessageBrokerClient messageBrokerClient = messageBrokerConfiguration.Name switch
    {
        MessageBrokerEnum.NotConfigured => new NotConfiguredClient(
            loggerFactory.CreateLogger<NotConfiguredClient>()),
        MessageBrokerEnum.AzureServiceBus => new AzureServiceBusClient(
            loggerFactory.CreateLogger<AzureServiceBusClient>()),
        MessageBrokerEnum.RabbitMq => new RabbitMqClient(
            loggerFactory.CreateLogger<RabbitMqClient>()),
        _ => new NotConfiguredClient(loggerFactory.CreateLogger<NotConfiguredClient>())
    };

    await messageBrokerContextService.SetMessageBrokerClientAsync(messageBrokerClient);
    await messageBrokerContextService.SendMessageAsync("Hello World!");

    await app.RunAsync();

    Console.ReadKey();
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    logger.LogError(exception, "Error occurred during startup");
}
```

My solution is available here - https://github.com/septst/MultiCloudClientSample

Though this works, I am not happy with certain things like explicitly instantiating clients using "new" as the the number of injected dependencies can grow. How can I use dependency injection in this case? Are there any alternatives or any suggestions to improve this solution?

Update: My solution is now updated with the answer from @Nkosi. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing the provided solution, I would suggest the following refactors *(see comments in code)*

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
builder.Logging.AddJsonConsole();

builder.Services.AddSingleton<IMessageBrokerContext, MessageBrokerContext>();

//Add configuration to container so it can be injected/resolved as needed.
builder.Services.AddSingleton<MessageBrokerConfiguration>(_ => 
    builder.Configuration.GetSection(MessageBrokerConfiguration.Position).Get<MessageBrokerConfiguration>()
);

//Configure the strategy for resolving the client using factory delegate
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IMessageBrokerClient>(sp => {
    //get configuration
    MessageBrokerConfiguration config = sp.GetRequiredService<MessageBrokerConfiguration>();
    //initialize client based on configuration
    IMessageBrokerClient client = config.Name switch {
        MessageBrokerEnum.NotConfigured => ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<NotConfiguredClient>(sp),
        MessageBrokerEnum.AzureServiceBus => ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<AzureServiceBusClient>(sp),
        MessageBrokerEnum.RabbitMq => ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<RabbitMqClient>(sp),
        _ => ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<NotConfiguredClient>(sp)
    };
    return client;
});

var app = builder.Build();
var logger = app.Logger;

try {
    IMessageBrokerContext messageBrokerContextService = 
        app.Services.GetRequiredService<IMessageBrokerContext>();

    await messageBrokerContextService.SendMessageAsync("Hello World!");

    await app.RunAsync();

    Console.ReadKey();
} catch (Exception exception) {
    logger.LogError(exception, "Error occurred during startup");
}
```

Note the use of `ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance` along with the service provider to create the instances of the clients to avoid any tight coupling to changes to the number of injected dependencies.

There was also no need to manually set the client via `SetMessageBrokerClientAsync` since the client is being explicitly injected when the context is being resolved.

The client configuration, since registered with the container, can now also be injected into the client implementations so that client specific run time data can be used.

```
public class RabbitMqClient : IMessageBrokerClient {
    private readonly ILogger<RabbitMqClient> logger;
    private readonly MessageBrokerConfiguration config;
    
    public RabbitMqClient(MessageBrokerConfiguration config, ILogger<RabbitMqClient> logger) {
        this.config = config;
        this.logger = logger;
        
        //Now have access to 
        //config.ConnectionString;
        //config.QueueName;
    }

    public async Task SendMessageAsync(string message) {
        logger.LogInformation("RabbitMQ Client sends message {Message}", message);
        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```